# How to redirect if not from $_SERVER['HTTP_REFERER']?

Tags: php

```
<?PHP
if (ereg("www\.test", $_SERVER['HTTP_REFERER']) != true)
{
    header("location http://www.example.com");
    end;
}
    echo "111";
        //dosomting?
?>
```

It still not working

Comment: `ereg` is deprecated. Use `preg_match`.

Comment: @netcoder Forgot about that. I updated my answer.

Comment: doesn't "location" inside the header() need a colon?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this:

```
<?php

   if (!preg_match("www\.test", $_SERVER['HTTP_REFERER'])) {
      header("Location: http://www.example.com");
      exit();
   }
   //do stuff...

?>
```